# CoreData: How to properly set created entity attributes

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, entity-attribute-value

I have a Core Data Entity, let's call it "Record", and I have several attributes that I need to set with data from other objects/entities (as well as setting up relationships).

Let's say "Record" has the following attributes:

```
@interface Record (CoreDataProperties)

+ (NSFetchRequest<Record *> *)fetchRequest;

@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *superRecordID;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *otherDataID;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSNumber *active;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSDate *createDate;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSDate *updateDate;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, copy) NSString *uuid;
@property (nullable, nonatomic, retain) SuperRecord *superRecord;

@end
```

I know for things such as active, I can set the default to 1 from XCode and for things such as createDate, updateDate and uuid, I can override the awakeFromInsert method.

My question is: what is the best practice for setting the other values and relationships upon creation? The only way I can think of that I know should work is to create the instance THEN set all the attributes, but is there a better way I can do this? Where I pass in the additional values/objects are parameters and set the attributes/relationships on creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply write a convenience allocator like this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithSuperRecord:(SuperRecord*)superRecord active:(BOOL)active … context:(NSManagdObjectContext*)context
{
  self = [super initWithEntity:… /* in subclasses you typically know that */ 
                insertIntoManagedObjectContext:context];
  if( self ) 
  {
     // Set the properties you get from the args
  }
  return self;
}

+ (instancetype)newWithSuperRecord:(SuperRecord*)superRecord active:(BOOL)active … context:(NSManagdObjectContext*)context
{
   return [[self alloc] initWithSuperRecord:superRecord … context:context];
}
```

Some suggestions: The superID seems to be a property of the super record. Don't store it twice. Moreover you should check, whether you need an ID at all. This is not OOPish. Boolean values should by typed to boolean values. Use `YES` and `NO` or `@YES` and `@NO` instead of 1 and 0.

Typed in Safari.

Comment: You are absolutely right about the ID field, my predecessor tried to keep the tables consistent with our webDB but having the object itself is more in line with OOP principles. I've opted to avoid going this route as I have spoken with a senior developer who advised that I avoid messing with the init methods, as Core Data does a lot of behind the scenes things I may be interfering with. I decided to just create the objects and set the attributes afterwards. I implemented your solution, however, and it worked as expected so you will mark your answer correct. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can do it that way, nothing wrong with it. However, I have an advice for your senior developer ;-) Even CD does many things *behind the scenes* on of the strength of Objective-C is that initialization is no language concept. It is completely outside the language. What you've learned about initialization in Objective-C is not defined by the language itself, but by the framework.

Comment: Therefore, initialization code is just usual code with some rules of the framework (still not the language). Initialization does nothing behind its scene. Therefore code in `-init…` is *normal* code. Putting code from outside into an initializer does not change anything, it is still regular code . So code you have outside in the initialization and code you have inside the initialization are simply the same and cannot cause harm to anything in the limelight or behind the scenes. CD does not even know, whether messages come from regular code or initializers, because there is no difference.

Comment: Therefore the advise of your senior developer could be, too: "Don't move the code for setting-up properties in a method called `setUpEntity` or even `-doSomething`, because "CD does something behind the scenes". Why should it matter? He wouldn't say it. But `-init…` is just another `-doSomething`.

Comment: actually I realized the superRecordID field is there so I have a way of connecting the objects together in a relationship when I am doing the mapping, so it is necessary. Also it is core data that sets bool attributes as NSNumber.

Comment: I do not understand, how your last comment is related to my last comments.

Comment: it's related to your first comment. "The superID seems to be a property of the super record. Don't store it twice. " I merely gave you the reason why.

Comment: Ah, it is related to the answer itself. CD supports relations. You do not have to manage an ID your own.

Comment: I'm using RestKit to map objects directly into CoreData. To add the relationships during mapping I need a reference to the object.

Ex.     [superRecordEntityMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"record" connectedBy:@{@"superRecordID":@"superRecordID"}];

If there is another way to do this then I don't know how.

Comment: Without knowing details of your code: If you need that for the mapping, why do you store it in the model after mapping?